# Stored Procedure using where with multiple if else and different table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Something]
(
    @Search_Text VARCHAR(4000),
    @FILTER INT
)
AS
BEGIN  
    SELECT  Customer_Information
    FROM    Customer
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Something K 
            ON  K.Something _Id= Something_Id2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Something3 KS 
            ON KS.Something_Id =Something_Id3
    WHERE
        (Filter = 1 AND Customer_İnformation LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')
        OR
        (Filter = 2 AND Customer_name LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')
        OR
        (Filter = 3 AND Customer_Adress LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')
END
```

I get all datas from **Customer Table**.

I need to get data from **PRODUCT_TABLE** for my below code,

```
(Filter = 3 AND Customer_Adress LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')
from PRODUCT_TABLE
```

how can i achieve this inside "where" in Ms Sql?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the Product table part of the query?

Comment: There is no product table in query. i need to write "from Product_Table"

Comment: If you want to check different table you need to fork the query with `IF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Something]
(
    @Search_Text VARCHAR(4000),
    @FILTER INT
)
AS
BEGIN  
    IF Filter IN (1,2)
    SELECT  Customer_Information
    FROM    Customer
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Something K 
            ON  K.Something _Id= Something_Id2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Something3 KS 
            ON KS.Something_Id =Something_Id3
    WHERE
        (Filter = 1 AND Customer_İnformation LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')
        OR
        (Filter = 2 AND Customer_name LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')
        OR
        (Filter = 3 AND Customer_Adress LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')

    IF Filter = 3
    SELECT  YourField
    FROM    ProductTable
    WHERE
        (Filter = 3 AND YourSearchField LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Something]
(
    @Search_Text VARCHAR(4000),
    @FILTER INT
)
AS
BEGIN  
    SELECT  Customer_Information
    FROM    Customer
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Something K 
            ON  K.Something _Id= Something_Id2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Something3 KS 
            ON KS.Something_Id =Something_Id3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  PRODUCT_TABLE P
            ON P.Something_Id = KS.Something_Id3

    WHERE
        (Filter = 1 AND Customer_İnformation LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')
        OR
        (Filter = 2 AND Customer_name LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')
        OR
        (Filter = 3 AND Customer_Adress LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')
        OR
        (P.Filter = 3 AND P.Customer_Adress LIKE '%' + @Search_Text + '%')

END
```

I think another thing you are missing here is, in your Where clause you havent mentioned anything about which Filter is from which table, Use the table alias before the column names like I have it makes code easier to read and easier to maintain and resolves column ambiguity .